# Is it possible to "anti optimise" Google AdWords for users who carry out a particular action?

Tags: google-ads

We are using Google AdWords Ads to drive traffic to a site.

The site has two contact forms on it each with a separate "thank you page" to track conversions.

The contact forms are as follows:

1. A sales lead form
2. a general contact form

The purpose of the sales lead form is to drive inquiries.

The purpose of the general contact form is for all other queries, and so people don't try and contact the website via the sales lead form, when their inquiry is not sales related, as if they did that the conversion optimisation in Google AdWords would become skewed.

Looking in Google Analytics I can see quite a bit of our paid traffic is going through to the general contact form. Eg. its not sales traffic. (But we are paying for them to visit!)

I'm aware you can tell Google AdWords to optimise a campaign for conversions, which we already have setup (eg. we have told Google Adwords to optimise the campaign for people completing the sales lead form) but is it possible to do the reverse and "anti optimise" eg. tell Google AdWords to not show ads to people who are likely to fill out the general (non sales) contact form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can.

Under **Tools & Settings > Audience Manager** create a segment for users that fill out the general contact form. You can either define this by a page visited (e.g. `/thank-you-page`) or by a dedicated conversion tag that you set to fire when form is submitted.

[image]

Once you have your segment set up you need to exclude it within your campaign or Ad group settings. Exclusions can be set at either level. Exclusions can also be set on App campaigns, but only at the campaign-level.

In the left hand menu bar navigate to **Audiences > Exclusions** and select the segment you created.

[image]

You can do this on Search, Display, Discovery, and Video campaigns. In the short term you will likely not see a difference, but over time as Google Ads gathers data about your segment you'll observe more and more precision.

Lastly, since you're creating an exclusion for users that fill out a form, you run a fairly high risk of your ads **not** being shown to users that otherwise would have completed your desired action.

For this reason you may be wise to **run this exclusion at the Ad group level to start** and see how it works.

**Note: Segments May be Impacted by iOS 14 Traffic**

> As Apple’s [App Tracking Transparency (ATT) policies](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/) go into effect, your data segments (especially website, app and automatically created segments) and Customer Match segments may be impacted on iOS 14 traffic (including the use of these segments for exclusions). Campaigns promoting web-based conversion goals - particularly those using Customer Match and your other data segments - may also see performance fluctuations. During this time we will be expanding [modeled conversions](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10081327) to more iOS 14 traffic.